# Could not resolve * to a component implementation with custom CalloutButton component

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4, namespaces, flex4.6

I've got a custom CalloutButton component in a package called uiComponents. This custom CallOutButton is needed because I need some more properties in it.

This CalloutButton gets added to my MXML like usual;

```
     <uiComponents:MyCustomCalloutButton someproperties here >

     </uiComponents:My...>
```

Now, the enclosed   s:calloutContent gets a compilation error, the (almost standard) could not resolve...

Naturally, the namespace has been imported

What am I missing here? This is driving me nuts for more than an hour now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: What is the compilation error?  Is this just a matter of you not importing the 'uiComponents' namespace at the top of your MXML file?

Comment: uiComponents has been imported (I already tried different namespaces, class names and packages in case that there is a flex internal class with a similar name). Oddly enough, the error doesn't occur at the MyCustomCallout line, rather than on the enclosed s:calloutContent tag. Instead of simply extending the CalloutButton class, I already copied the whole content of it to my CustomCallout, so I reckon there's an issue with encapsulated spark components in a component with a different namespace (although that works fine for components other than the Callout).

Comment: Show us the code where you inport the uiComponents namespace.  If the error occurs on an enclosed callout tag; why didn't you show us that line?  In many situations, enclosed tags must use the same namespace as their parent, so replace it with "uiComponents:calloutContent"

Comment: I did not know that. Worked perfectly fine. Thank you very much! Appreciate it!

Comment: I posted that as a formal answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the error was generated from the `s:calloutContent` tag ; not the `uiComponents:MyCustomCallOutButton` tag; the solution was that in many situations, enclosed tags must use the same namespace as their parent, so replace it with `uiComponents:calloutContent`

So instead of this:

```
 <uiComponents:MyCustomCalloutButton someproperties here >
     <s:calloutContent />
 </uiComponents:My...>
```

You'll need to do this:

```
 <uiComponents:MyCustomCalloutButton someproperties here >
     <uiComponents:calloutContent />
 </uiComponents:My...>
```